# Tabulary package does not print table with correct size

Tags: tables

I want to re-create this table:
[image]
and I spent hours to understand tables in `LaTeX` and figure out what package I need. All I got was frustration.

My MWE outputs the following table and I expected it to have the width of linewidth (as specified), but it does not. I used `LaTeX` for several months now, but never really worked with tables and they don't feel practical to me. Now, how do I get to get the table to the right size?

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[12pt, listof=totoc, numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\begin{document}
This is an MWE and some Text to see how much space there is in one Line... more than enough.
\begin{table}[!h]
    \caption{My Tabel}
    \centering
    \begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{L|C C C C C C} \toprule % expecting the table to have the width of \linewidth
        Temperaturbereich in C 
        & \multicolumn{6}{c}{
        \begin{tabular}{c|c}$T_1 = 1$ & $T_2 = 2$\end{tabular}} 
        \\ \midrule
        Approximationsfunktion  
        & \multicolumn{6}{c}{$\displaystyle c_{Fe2O3} = \frac{123}{321}$}
        \\ \midrule
        Konstanten 
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$123$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$321$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$444$}
        \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabulary}
    \label{tab:Koeff-Fe2O3}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know enough about tabulary to help, but do note that booktabs hates vertical lines, and will make it very difficult (or impossible) to join them up.  Many on this site will say that your table will look better without the vertical lines and most of the horizontal lines.

Comment: `\linewidth` here set not the width but the maximal width. To extent the table to the maximal width you can (1) add more content (2) set `\tabcolsep`  to  a huge 2.7em or so, or (3) use `tabularx` that set the width (not the maximal width) and then mess with the align of X columns. But you can also simply accept that a little table centered is better than a   table stretched out without measure.

Comment: why declare 7 column table when no row has 7 columns? but tabulary doesn't stretch the table if the natural width is less than the target

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As complement to nice @Mico answer (+1), by use of the `tabularray` package. It enable a bit shorter code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, listof=totoc, numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabularray} % for 'tblr' environment and 'X' col. type
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath,% for \dfrac
                siunitx}% for unit \degreeCelsius
\usepackage{mhchem}     % for '\ce' macro

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!h]
\caption{My Table}
\label{tab:Koeff-Fe2O3}

\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = { l *{6}{X[c, mode=math]} },
             rowsep  = 4pt
             }
Temperaturbereich in \unit{\degreeCelsius}
    &   \SetCell[c=3]{} T_1 = 1
        &   &   &   \SetCell[c=3]{} T_2 = 2
                    &   &                   \\
Approximationsfunktion
    &   \SetCell[c=6]{} c^{}_{\ce{Fe2O3}} = \dfrac{123}{321}
        &   &   &   &   &                   \\
Konstanten
    &   \SetCell[c=2]{} 123
        &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{} 456
                &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{} 789
                        &                   \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As the comments below the OP's query note, the `tabulary` machinery would appear to be unsuitable for the task at hand. Here's a solution that employs the `tabularx` machinery instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, listof=totoc, numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{tabularx} % for 'tabularx' env. and 'X' col. type
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for '\dfrac' macro
\usepackage{mhchem}   % for '\ce' macro

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered version of 'X'
\newcommand\mc[3]{% handy shortcut macro
    \multicolumn{#1}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr #2 \relax}C|}{#3}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a less-cramped "look"
\caption{My Table}
\label{tab:Koeff-Fe2O3}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ | l | *{6}{C|} } 
\hline 
Temperaturbereich in C 
  & \mc{3}{3\hsize+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth}{$T_1 = 1$}
  & \mc{3}{3\hsize+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth}{$T_2 = 2$}
\\ \hline
Approximationsfunktion  
  & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{%
    $c^{}_{\ce{Fe2O3}} = \dfrac{123^{\mathstrut}}{321_{\mathstrut}}$}
\\ \hline
Konstanten 
  & \mc{2}{2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+1\arrayrulewidth}{$123$} 
  & \mc{2}{2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+1\arrayrulewidth}{$321$} 
  & \mc{2}{2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+1\arrayrulewidth}{$444$}
\\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
    
\end{table}
\end{document}
```